# Why is my PHP case statement not working?

Tags: php

below is my code. fairly straight ahead. only the default condition is executing. the commented out else if statement does work. am trying to replace with a switch statment.

```
$currCat = (int)$_GET['cPath'];

switch ($currCat) {
case 4:
$tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_threads.php';
case 1:
$tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_canvas.php';    
case 3:
$tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_belts.php';     
case 85:
$tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_books.php';
case 75:
$tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_beltsDEV.php';
default:
$tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display.php';
}
/*
if($currCat == 4) {
$tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_threads.php';
} elseif ($currCat == 1) {
$tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_canvas.php'; 
etc. etc. */
```

big thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

You need to put `break` statements in between each case unless you want them to cascade (which I assume you don't)

```
switch ($currCat) {
    case 4 :
        $tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_threads.php';
        break;
    case 1 :
        $tpl_page_body = '/tpl_product_info_display_canvas.php'; 
        break;
    // and so on
}
```

Have a thorough read of http://php.net/manual/control-structures.switch.php